# undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass while deleting association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have

```
class Clot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

and same for users

I have follow button with action

```
def follow
    @clot = Clot.find(params[:id])
    @clot.users << current_user
    redirect_to @clot
end
```

Its working fine but i want to create unfollow button

i wrote

```
= button_to 'unollow', unfollow_clot_path(@clot), :method => :delete
```

with

```
  def unfollow
    @clot.users.destroy
  end
```

My routes looks like

```
 resources :clots do
      member do
        post :follow
        delete :unfollow
      end
  end
```

but i am getting error. please tell me answer and also tell me right way if i am doing it wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `@clot` you didn't have that in unfollow method like you have in follow `@clot = Clot.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @Sontya but what about  unfollow_clot_path(@clot)?

Comment: is it pass @clot to unfollow method ?

Comment: It will call unfollow method for that object @clot, Then in mtheod you have to find it `@clot = Clot.find(params[:id])`

Comment: that error gone but @clot.users.destroy not working

Comment: So `@clot.users` will give you an array, you can't call `destory` on that find `first` element and call `destory!` e.g. `@clot.users.first.destroy!`

Comment: @Sontya ok got it thanks i am new to ror and was unable to find that on intrenet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say this, it will call controller method unfollow, and in params will pass `clot id`. So you have to find that clot object with that id

```
 = button_to 'unollow', unfollow_clot_path(@clot), :method => :delete

def method_name
    @clot = Clot.find(params[:id])
end
```

But When you will do

`@clot.users`

It will return array of user for that clot instance. And you can't call `destroy` method on `array` object. So `first` will return you the first found object,So you can write like

```
@clot.users.first.destory!
```

Or you can also use `destory_all` method. To destroy all objects